# Can't login with new users, only old users (Django Rest Framework views.obtain_auth_token)

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I first noticed this after I deployed my site, but I checked when running it locally and I get the same issue, so I guess this was happening before deployment without me noticing.

Posting log in credentials for new users to obtain a token using DRF views.obtain_auth_token only works for users that I created early in the project, not new ones (trying to login with new users returns a bad request cant login in with user credentials).  I don't understand why because new users are still created, and appear in the admin User panel along with the old users, and I can see tokens are still generated for new users created.

I'm guessing it might be because I've done something wrong when changing the user model, but I'm fairly sure I created the first users after I changed it, so I'm not really sure.  Here is my user model:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        '''Create and save a user with the given email, and
        password.
        '''
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must have is_staff=True.'
            )
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'
            )

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=255,
        blank=False,
    )

    # All these field declarations are copied as-is
    # from `AbstractUser`
    first_name = models.CharField(
        _('first name'),
        max_length=30,
        blank=True,
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        _('last name'),
        max_length=150,
        blank=True,
    )
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether the user can log into '
            'this admin site.'
        ),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be '
            'treated as active. Unselect this instead '
            'of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(
        _('date joined'),
        default=timezone.now,
    )

    # Add additional fields here if needed

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

**EDIT:**

Would it be possible for something in the virtual environment that would cause this.  Before deployment something happened with my virtual environment where pip would no longer work. I couldn't fix it so recreated the virtual environment.

Comment: ensure that the new users are active

Comment: thanks for the response, users are active

Comment: did you set the AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings to point to the new user model?

Comment: yeah AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'goal.User'. I'm wondering if something happened/ I accidentally changed something when I switched from sqlite to postgres on AWS.  But if the database is still creating users successfully it must be connected right?